# Interactive parameters from bundle

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, bundles

I'm developing my first bundle in Symfony2, are services that make use of some parameters in its construction and was working properly if I keep this structure, in **AcmeBundle/Resource/config/parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    id: IDVAL
    secret: SECRETVAL

services:
    my_service:
        class: MyClass
        arguments: [%id%, %secret%]
```

But I wonder if there is any way to make use of [Interactive Management of the parameters.yml File](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file), for the installation of the bundle through the use of composer AcmeBundle/Resource/config/parameters.yml.dist is made instead of app/config/parameters.yml.dist

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do that through composer, when you're creating a reusable bundle.
Instead you can configure your bundle based on the `config.yml` file, using symfony's [Configuration Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html), and make those parameters required, this way when you're bundle is installed the user, will have to provide those parameters.  For you're use case it will be something like:

```
// in YourBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration
public function getConfigTreeBuilder(){
  $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
  $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('your_bundle_alias');
  $rootNode
    ->children()
      ->scalarNode('param1')->isRequired()->end()
      ->scalarNode('param1')->isRequired()->end()
    ->end();
 }
```

---

```
// in YourBundle\DependencyInjection\YourExtension
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container){

  $configuration = new Configuration();
  $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
  // ...
  // get the parameters entered in the config file, and configured above
  $param1 = $config['param1'];
  $param2 = $config['param2'];
  // inject them into my_service
  $container->getDefinition('my_service')
    ->setArguments(array($param1, $param2));
// ...
}
```

---

Writing your Bundle Configuration this way will force the user to provide an entry for your bundle in the `config.yml` file like the following:

```
your_bundle_alias:
  param1: the_users_value
  param2: another_value
```